# Purim donation card sources

Tags: purim, tzedakah-charity, product-recommendation, mishloach-manot

What are some organizations that produce "Money was donated for [Matanot Le'evyonim](http://www.ou.org/torah/article/purim_mitzvot#evyonim) in your honor in lieu of [Mishloach Manot](http://www.ou.org/torah/article/purim_mitzvot#mishloachmanot)" cards, with national, international, or Israeli scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there are plenty of local organizations that do them too; check your school, synagogue, benevolent societies such as Bikur Cholim, and other local charities (such as Tomchei Shabbos or Ahavas Yisrael). You may want to consult your rabbi regarding how to spread your charity funds between local, national, international, and Israeli needs. But as far as non-local, here's what I've seen so far; I'm opening this up as a wiki, so feel free to add.

- http://www.shopyadsarah.org/
- http://amitchildren.org/shop/ (website currently unhappy with my browser)
- [Yad Eliezer](http://www.yadeliezer.org/cards.php?id=243)
- [Yad Ezra V'Shulamit](http://www.yadezra.net/)
- [Misaskim](http://www.misaskim.org/) For helping with meis mitzvah or people needing help dealing with a tragedy.
- [Chai Lifeline](http://www.chailifeline.org) For helping children with serious illness and their families

Comment: Point well taken. In my previous city, I did indeed use a local organization's cards. I'm looking into local organizations off-line. I feel that this list could be useful for people who don't have a local option they like or who want to donate to and/or promote national/international/Israeli charities through this medium.